# Python: How do I provide my own ObjectID / _id when I insert into a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

I'm inserting information regarding some files into a MongoDB, among other things a checksum for the file. I want to use the checksum as the _id for the document. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You would set the _id field explicitly on the document you are storing. For example:

```
document = {}
document['_id'] = my_id
```

Please note that the _id value has to be unique for every document. Only store checksum as _id if you know that it will be unique.